# how to get unicode character from a unicode string in php

Tags: php, unicode

I want to get a single unicode chatacter from a unicode string.

for example:- 
$str = "पर्वत निर्माणों में कोनसा संचलन  कार्य करता है";
echo $str[0];

output is:- �

but i want to get char 'प' at 0 index of the string.

plz help me how to get char 'प' instead of � .

Comment: `mb_substr` may help you

Answer (score 6):

As @deceze writes, you need to use [`mb_substr`](http://php.net/mb_substr) in order to get a character, instead of just a byte. In addition, you need to set the internal encoding with [mb_internal_encoding](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-internal-encoding.php). Assuming that the encoding of your .php file is UTF-8, the following should work:

```
  mb_internal_encoding('utf-8');
  $str = "पर्वत निर्माणों में कोनसा संचलन कार्य करता है"; 
  echo mb_substr($str, 0, 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

PHP's default `$str[x]` notation operates on *bytes*, so you're just getting the first part of a multibyte character. To extract entire encoding aware byte sequences for whole characters, you need to use [`mb_substr`](http://php.net/mb_substr).

Also see [What Every Programmer Absolutely, Positively Needs To Know About Encodings And Character Sets To Work With Text](http://kunststube.net/encoding/).