# can $str[n] be used for string of Chinese characters?

Tags: php, string, utf-8

```
<?php   
    $str ='如果';
    var_dump($str[1]);
    echo '<br />';
    var_dump(ord($str[1]));
    echo '<br />';
    echo mb_substr($str , 1 , 1)
?>
```

This will output something like:

> string(1) "�"
>
> int(166)
>
> 果

I want to get the second character `果`, `mb_substr` can correctly get it, while $str[n] doesn't work. Is it possible at all to use `$str[n]` to deal with utf-8 characters?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to get unicode character from a unicode string in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27873995/how-to-get-unicode-character-from-a-unicode-string-in-php)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

UTF-8 uses multiple bytes to represent Unicode characters outside the ASCII range (U+00000 through U+0007F). Your string `如果` (U+05982 U+0679C) is represented as the six bytes:

```
0xE5 0xA6 0x82 0xE6 0x9E 0x9C
-------------- --------------
  (U+05982)      (U+0679C)
```

PHP is not natively Unicode-aware; it treats all strings as a sequence of bytes, not of Unicode characters. As such, `$str[1]` extracts the second *byte* (0xA6 = 166) from this sequence, not the second *character*. This is a continuation byte, so it is invalid when present alone, and it is displayed as the replacement character �.

Do not use character indexing on UTF-8 strings. For correct behavior, you must use the `mb_` functions.